# Why do arrays of length 1 behave like scalars inJavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, type-conversion

Example:

```js
let a = [1, 2]
console.log(a * 2);  // NaN, this isn't Python
a = [3];
console.log(a);  // an array, as expected: [3]
console.log(a * 2);  // 6!
```

This happens to be useful in practice with Headers objects, which typically contain arrays of 1 element:

```
// calculate when an API will reset its rate limit
new Date(response.headers['x-rate-limit-reset'] * 1000)
```

But why does it work?

Answer (score 2):

This is because during multiplication(`*`) [`type conversion`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Type_conversion) happens:

```js
console.log(Number([1, 2])); // NaN

console.log(Number([2]));   // 2
```

**NOTE**: Before converting to `Number` type JavaScript tries to convert the array into `String` which yields an comma separated value like `'1,2'` and `'2'`. Then, when JavaScript tries to convert those string back to `Number`(because we are multiplying them), `'1,2'` yields `NaN` whereas `'2'` get's converted just fine.

See for yourself:

```js
console.log(String([1,2]));   // '1,2' (of type string)
console.log(String([2]));     // '2' (of type string)
console.log(Number('1,2'));   // NaN (of type number)
console.log(Number('2'));     // 2 (of type number)
```

For more info see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness).

Comment: Indeed, this can even be extended to more levels: `console.log(Number([[[2]]]));   // 2`

Answer (score 1):

When an array is in an expression where a primitive is expected, its `toString` method is called. For arrays, this is basically `arr.join(',')`. Strings containing commas cannot be converted to numbers:

```js
let a = [1, 2]
console.log(a * 2);  // doesn't work
console.log('1, 2' * 2) // same string result: also doesn't work
console.log([1, 2].toString() === '1,2');
```

But when `join(',')` is called on an array with one element, there are no commas, so the result *can* be converted to a number and multiplied with `*`.

```js
console.log([3].toString());
console.log([3, 4].toString());
console.log(isNaN([3].toString()));
console.log(isNaN([3, 4].toString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with JavaScript sameness.

Check this page for the full documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

A lot of automatic conversion can happen :)

Here is a strange/funny one:

```js
console.log([1, 2] == '1,2')
```

So that explains it:

```js
console.log([6] == '6');
console.log([6] == 6);
console.log([6] * '7');
```

`*` is a mathematical operator and it tries to cast everything to number! `[6]` can be casted to `6`, the same way than `'7'` can be casted to `7` and here it is!

Comment: The first example isn't strange. `[1, 2] == '1,2'` means `String([1,2]) == '1,2'` depend on both sides' type.

Answer (score 1):

The comprehensive answer you can find here:
[Official specification: ToNumber](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tonumber)